# Unity Jenkins/Command Line Build

Tags: unity-game-engine, jenkins

I am trying to build my project from command line; the same command would be used in Jenkins. When I fire the build command, from terminal on Mac, I get infinite request Asset garbage collection. The build works fine from the Editor UI.

**Command:**

/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.15f1/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity -batchmode -nographics -buildTarget Android -serial snipped -username snipped -password snipped -projectPath /Users/amit/code/myproject -executeMethod build_script_v7.PerformBuild

**Infinite messages that I get:**

Refreshing native plugins compatible for Editor in 1.29 ms, found 10 plugins.

Preloading 0 native plugins for Editor in 0.00 ms.

Asset Pipeline Refresh: Total: 0.265 seconds - Initiated by StopAssetImportingV2(NoUpdateAssetOptions)

[UnityConnectServicesConfig] config is NOT valid, switching to default

[00:00:00] Finished 1 Bake Ambient Probe job (0.00s execute, 0.00s integrate, 0.62s wallclock)

[Licensing::Module] Successfully cleared the access token

[Licensing::Module] Successfully updated access token: "eTAm46kh"... (expires: 2023-03-20 15:24:46 GMT)

User  logged in successfully

Request Asset Garbage Collect because used heap size increased from 7.0 MB to 7.0 MB, exceeding the threshold of 256.0 MB.

Unloading 94 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)

Unloading 275 unused Assets / (3.5 KB). Loaded Objects now: 13357.

Memory consumption went from 7.0 MB to 6.9 MB.

Total: 61.144667 ms (FindLiveObjects: 8.161917 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.360041 ms MarkObjects: 50.952667 ms DeleteObjects: 1.669292 ms)

Request Asset Garbage Collect because used heap size increased from 6.9 MB to 6.9 MB, exceeding the threshold of 4294967296.00 GB.

Unloading 0 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)

Unloading 0 unused Assets / (41.5 KB). Loaded Objects now: 13357.

Memory consumption went from 6.9 MB to 6.9 MB.

Total: 10.687334 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.421958 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.241583 ms MarkObjects: 9.976292 ms DeleteObjects: 0.046875 ms)

Request Asset Garbage Collect because used heap size increased from 6.9 MB to 6.9 MB, exceeding the threshold of 4294967296.00 GB.

Unloading 0 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)

Unloading 0 unused Assets / (0 B). Loaded Objects now: 13357.

Memory consumption went from 6.9 MB to 6.9 MB.

Total: 8.680625 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.358958 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.144292 ms MarkObjects: 8.167375 ms DeleteObjects: 0.009750 ms)

> Request Asset Garbage Collect because used heap size increased from
> 6.9 MB to 6.9 MB, exceeding the threshold of 4294967296.00 GB.
>
> Unloading 0 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
>
> Unloading 0 unused Assets / (0 B). Loaded Objects now: 13357.
>
> Memory consumption went from 6.9 MB to 6.9 MB.
>
> Total: 8.121250 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.295292 ms CreateObjectMapping:
> 0.118958 ms MarkObjects: 7.697250 ms DeleteObjects: 0.009375 ms)

The above 5 lines keep repeating, infinitely. No build happens. The threshold also does not make much sense.

Comment: Have you tried leaving out the `-nographics` option? We never use that on our Jenkins builds and I've never seen the errors you describe.

Comment: @frankhermes `-nographics` shouldn't be a issue - it even is required in places where your server doesn't have a GPU - I used this all the time and never had any issues either .. rather looks like some weird memory issue, never seen this tbh. @OP have you tried running the command on your Jenkins server manually? What platform is your Jenkins server running on?

Comment: Jenkins is running on Mac. I have tried running the command manually. When I omit nographics, "nothing" happens - when I hit enter on the command line nothing gets printed on command line, no UI pops up. With nographics options, the command line comes alive with all sorts of messages.